# Asp.Net MVC 3 ModelBinding Arrays

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I am posting something that looks like this:

```
  FavoritePerson: "Dennis"
  FavoriteAnimals: [{Type="Bear", Name="Bruno"}, {Type="Shark", Name="Sammy"}, ...]
```

Is there some shape for the Model to be that the DefaultModelBinder would be able to handle this?  Something like

```
class FavoriteAnimalSubmission {
  string Type {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}
}
[HttpPost]
public MarkFavorites(string favoritePerson, FavoriteAnimalSubmission[] favoriteAnimals[]) {
...
}
```

Will fill favoritePerson and favoriteAnimals.Count but not the properties on each animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing out of the box that will handle a mixture of JSON (which in your case is invalid) and standard url encoded parameters. You will have to write a custom model binder if you ever needed to handle this request. Or simply modify your request to:

```
{
    "FavoriteAnimals": [
        {
            "Type": "Bear",
            "Name": "Bruno"
        },
        {
            "Type": "Shark",
            "Name": "Sammy"
        }
    ],
    "FavoritePerson": "Dennis"
}
```

and then on the server:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string FavoritePerson { get; set; }
    public FavoriteAnimalSubmission[] FavoriteAnimals { get; set; }
}

public class FavoriteAnimalSubmission
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public MarkFavorites(MyViewModel model) 
{
    ...
}
```

and the AJAX request to invoke it:

```
var model = 
    {
        "FavoriteAnimals": [
            {
                "Type": "Bear",
                "Name": "Bruno"
            },
            {
                "Type": "Shark",
                "Name": "Sammy"
            }
        ],
        "FavoritePerson": "Dennis"
    };

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("MarkFavorites", "SomeController")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function(result) {
        // do something with the result
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not mixing request and post parameters, I'm doing the same thing that you are. Are you saying it should work? Maybe I'm missing something.